# c# freezes in exception

Tags: c#, .net, task

I'm having a strange behaviour since I started using Tasks.

This is my program class

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var escuchar = Task.Factory.StartNew(RunListener);
        var escucharComandos = Task.Factory.StartNew(TaconetListener.Escuchar);
        Task.WaitAll(new[] { escuchar, escucharComandos });
    }
}

private static void RunListener()
    {
        try
        {
            _udpListener = new UdpListener(UdpSettings.Settings.Puerto);
            Console.WriteLine("Escuchando en: {0}", UdpSettings.Settings.Puerto);
            while (true)
            {
                var received = _udpListener.Recibir();
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Procesar(received));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something exploded: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Whenever an exception is hit in "Procesar", this happens:

[image]

It's stuck there, it won't continue.

If I move the instruction pointer to the following line, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: this happens every run

Comment: also I can't see which exception is thrown.

Comment: Enable Break when exception is thrown ([VS2013 and older instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.120).aspx), [VS2015 and newer instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx#Anchor_0)), then [copy the exception detail to the clicpboad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) and post it here as a edit to your question.

Comment: Also, you can use `ex.ToString()` instead of `ex.Message` to get more exception detail in your logs, for example it includes the type of the exception and the stack trace.

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown, but why the catch freezes?

Comment: Check my image, "Procesar" method.. It's stuck in that line, F10 or F5 makes the program continue waiting on the "Task.WaitAll" line but nothing happens, just stuck there.

Comment: If the Procesar throws it'll break out of the while loop and not receive anything anymore. It will then sit waiting for the `escucharComandos` to finish, does that give any indication? To make it continue listening you'd need to move the try/catch inside the while loop

Comment: escuchar and escucharComandos are two udp listeners on different ports. Each of them creates a new Task whenever a datagram is received and calls Procesar which parses the datagram. Procesar will never throw upwards an exception since it'll break out of the while loop. This is why I catch every exception in Procesar and just log it.

Comment: Please do not use bitmap images as the primary mode to convey your problem. **Type** or **copy/paste** as text a complete description of the problem, error, exception, etc. Please do provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.